# Normal Approximation to the Binomial question

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, binomial-distribution

I have a question I need help on:

> A supermarket manager samples n = 50 customers and if the true fraction of customers who dislike the policy is approximately .9, find the probability that the sample fraction will be within .15 unit of the true fraction

From this information, we know for the binomial distribution that n = 50 and p = 0.9. If I am correct, the sample proportion (we'll call it p') can be approximated as $N(p,\sqrt{p(q)/n})$. Therefore, it follows that what we are trying to find is the probability that $p(|p' - p)| \le 0.15)$ = $P(-0.15 \le p' - p \le 0.15)$

At this point, I'm kind of stuck. I know that I need to get Z where p' - p is, but I'm not sure what to do. If I understand correctly, the sample proportion can be represented as $\dfrac{Y}{n}$, leaving $P(-0.15 \le \dfrac{Y}{n} - p \le 0.15)$ but I'm not sure I understand why. Would someone be able to help me work through this? I really appreciate your help in advanced! Thanks!

However, at this point, I'm kind of stuck. I know that I need to get Z where p' - p is, but I'm not sure what to do. Would someone be able to help me work through this? I really appreciate your help in advanced! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The idea of the normal approximation to the binomial is to use a normal distribution whose mean and variance equals that of the binomial distribution mean and variance; i.e., if the sample is drawn from a random variable $X \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n,p)$, then $$X \overset{\circ}{\sim} \operatorname{Normal}(\mu = np, \sigma^2 = np(1-p)).$$  Equivalently, we may express this approximation in terms of the **sampling distribution of the sample proportion**, e.g., $$\hat p = \frac{X}{n} \overset{\circ}{\sim} \operatorname{Normal}\left(\mu = p, \sigma^2 = \frac{p(1-p)}{n} \right).$$  This approximation then allows us to compute relevant probabilities using normal distribution tables.  In your case, $n = 50$, $p = 0.9$, $\sigma = \sqrt{(0.9)(0.1)/50} \approx 0.0424264$, and the desired probability is the probability that the sample proportion $\hat p$ is within $0.15$ units of the true proportion $p$: $$\Pr[|\hat p - p| < 0.15] = \Pr[-0.15 < \hat p - 0.9 < 0.15].$$  If we now standardize by writing the above probability as $$\Pr\left[ \frac{-0.15}{0.0424624} < \frac{\hat p - \mu}{\sigma} < \frac{0.15}{0.0424624} \right],$$ we see the random variable in the center of this inequality is a standard normal variable with mean $0$ and standard deviation $1$.  Thus the above probability is simply $$\Pr[-3.53553 < Z < 3.53553] = 1 - 2 \Pr[Z > 3.53553] \approx 0.999593.$$

However, the *exact* probability corresponds to the quantity $$\begin{align*} \Pr[0.9 - 0.15 < X/n < 0.9 + 0.15] &= \Pr[0.75(50) < X] \\ &= \Pr[X \ge 38] \\ &= \sum_{x=38}^{50} \binom{50}{x} (0.9)^x (1 - 0.9)^{50-x} \\ &\approx 0.998995. \end{align*}$$  This sum, which contains 13 terms, is difficult to calculate except with a computer or very sophisticated calculator.  Note that the exact probability is smaller than the normal approximation value; this is due to the fact that the sample proportion cannot actually take on continuous values, but is discrete because the number of dissatisfied customers in a sample of size $n = 50$ is necessarily an integer between $0$ and $50$; thus in order for the sample proportion to be within $0.15$ of the true proportion of $p = 0.9$, this means $X > 37.5$; but $X$ cannot actually be, say, $37.7$--hence the rounding up to $X \ge 38$.  The upper bound is ignored because if $0.9 + 0.15 = 1.05 > 1$, so in effect, the upper bound is $X \le 50$.  So on both ends of the interval, the normal approximation includes a tiny bit of "extra" probability that is not counted using the exact binomial distribution.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I really appreciate it! Detailed and really helps my understanding! I have one question though, do you think you could explain how you went from $$\Pr[|\hat p - p| < 0.15] = \Pr[-0.15 < \hat p - 0.9 < 0.15].$$  to $$\Pr\left[ \frac{-0.15}{0.0424624} < \frac{\hat p - \mu}{\sigma} < \frac{0.15}{0.0424624} \right]$$ ? I'm not sure I understand where the -0.9 went.

Comment: I kind of went "backward."  In fact, $\mu = p = 0.9$.  $\mu$ is the mean of the normal distribution; $p$ is the true proportion of dissatisfied customers.  $\hat p$ is the sample proportion that was observed (and is a random variable whose outcome depends on the sample).  So $\hat p - 0.9 = \hat p - \mu$ under the normal approximation that $\mu = p$.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I also had one more question, how do you solve $P(x \le Z \le y)$? In our case, I see how $1-P(x \le z)$ allows for $P(z \le x)$, but do you combine it such that $1-p(z \le x) + p(z \le y)$?

Comment: $Pr[x \le Z \le y] = \Phi(y) - \Phi(x)$, where $\Phi$ is the CDF of the standard normal distribution.  In the TI-83 calculator, this is `[2nd] -> [DISTR] -> normalcdf(x, y, 0, 1)`.  Notice that the calculator takes *both* endpoints as arguments.  The third and fourth arguments are the mean and standard deviation, respectively.  So instead of standardizing, you could have also entered `normalcdf(-0.15, 0.15, 0.9, 0.0424624)` directly.

Comment: In this case then, why do you then do $1-2Pr[Z > 3.53553]$ which I believe is the same as $(1-Pr[-3.5355 \le Z) - P(Z \le 3.53553)$? (Thanks again for your help in my understanding!)

Comment: Because if you don't use a calculator, and instead a normal distribution table, then such tables are one-tailed.  It so happens that in our case, $x = -y$ (the area to be computed under the standard normal curve is symmetric), so that's why I wrote $1 - 2\Pr[Z > 3.53553]$.  But this is the same as $\Pr[Z \le 3.53553] - \Pr[Z \le -3.53553]$.  How you do it depends on what tools you have available.

Comment: So the tables only do $P(Z \le x)$? Thus because they are one tailed, then you have to do $1 - P(Z \le y)$ to get the correct result?